# jooq field values are null when run via junit

Tags: java, junit, jooq

I've created a list of columns that I want to retrieve as so:

```
final Field ciNameField = field("some_column");
...
```

I put these into a list as so:

```
ImmutableList<Field> columns = ImmutableList.<Field>builder()
            .add(ciNameField)
            ...
            .build();
```

and finally use these in my query:

```
Result<Record> fetchMetadata = context.select(columns.asList())
     ...
     .fetch();
```

This works fine when run as an integration test but has problems when I try to unit test it. Specifically the `field(String)` is returning null.

Im setting up the test as follows:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DSL.class})
public class ServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    PostgresDatasource pgClient;

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void checkParamsUsedTest() {
        DSLContext context = mock(DSLContext.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DSL.class);

        ...
```

and so on.

Other than this snag the mocking / testing works fine.

Im guessing there's either some setup for jooq / fields that I've missed or some testing caveat where this type of operation isn't supported.

---

## Edit:

Other jooq methods that don't seem to work when run via PowerMockito:

- name
- (un)quotedName

These return null.

Comment: Do you really want to mock the entire DSL? That sounds like a lot of effort and maintenance. Surely there are better hooks that you can mock, e.g. the service itself? What's the goal of your mocking approach?

Comment: Im hoping to check the validity of each place where I input values - column names, 'where', etc. Standard unit test things. The only snag Ive found (so far) is the 'field()' method. If I take all the columns and use a 'where("column = ?", column_name)' I can mock each step and check what I need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "checking the validity of each place", or "check what I need". I'm sure there's a better way to achieve what you want to do, but your question wasn't about that, it was about mocking, and some third party mocking library...

Comment: I want to insure that the params that I pass into this method are being used. The end goal is to write covering unit tests for this method: missing / invalid params, exception handling, etc.

Comment: I see. I would use `Query.getBindValues()` on an actual query, instead of a mocked one, to validate this... Or run integration tests.

Comment: Yeah - the integration testing works fine. It's all the Final and Static that are causing me problems.. No matter. jooq certainly isn't the issue here. It's a 'me problem'.